# How we can update Windows Phone 8 Flip Tile back image in a 5 minute interval using ShellTileSchedule?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 application i want to `update Flip Tile Back Image` from a list of recent images. 
I implemented it by using `ScheduledTaskAgent`. But it is limiting the app to update image in 30 minutes interval. How we can update it in `5 minutes` ? Is there any way of doing this by using `ShellTileSchedule`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShellTileSchedule` only supports valid intervals as defined in the [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.updateinterval%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

The only way to have tiles update on a frequency of every 5 minutes will be to send the updated details via a push notification.
See [How to send and receive Tile notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi,

Yes Matt is right, am using push notification to update my tiles frequently,,,,,

Comment: hi @Noorul can we update tile with locally saved images by using push notification service ?

Comment: sorry , am not sure with the locally stored images, i am updating images by their remote url, and if the image is in our app, like splash screen, background images, we can use that images too.

Comment: @Noorul Thanks for the answer.  But do you know what about images stored in isolated storage in this case ?

Comment: hi, i didn't tried that yet, you just try to do this and let me know the possibility, try to convert that image stored in isolated storage into Image or BitmapImage, and try to set that image as the BackgroundImage of that tile.